# Knn and euclidean distance

Tags: machine-learning, classification, distance, k-nn, mathematics

I'm studying the knn classification algorithm.
Why can the euclidean distance be considered a nice measure of affinity between examples ?

In one dimension (1 attribute) this seems correct, but if I add dimensions, can the euclidean distance still be considerd a good measure of affinity? Why?

Comment: Your premise is incorrect. Euclidean distance is not the only distance function used for knn or k-means or etc. These models can work with **any** distance function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can think of examples as vectors in $\mathbb{R}^p$, where $p$ is the number of features. Two examples will be very similar if the distance between them is close to $0$ (in the extreme case, if two examples are equal their euclidean distance is $0$). One way to measure the distance is using euclidean distance, but other distances can be used, as cosine distance or $L^p$ metrics. In fact, if $p$ is very high, then Euclidean distance is not a good measure, as it tends to make the distances too uniform (see [this paper](https://bib.dbvis.de/uploadedFiles/155.pdf)).

**Edit: When $p$ is very high:**

See [this magnificient answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/99171/why-is-euclidean-distance-not-a-good-metric-in-high-dimensions) to the issues that very high $p$ may have.

Comment: Growing the dimensions the distances get bigger. But maybe it's not a problem and maybe the euclidean distance still gives a good measure of affinity. Why not ?

Comment: Do you mean when $p$ is very high?

Comment: When p is greater than 2

Comment: When $p$ is not very big, the euclidean distance works. What's the problem with that?

Comment: In practice, growing the dimensions and considering euclidean distance, you are giving more "degrees of freedom"  to the examples to be considered affine to the query example. Am i correct ?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by affine? Close?

Comment: (i''ve corrected) In practice, growing the dimensions and considering euclidean distance, you are giving more "degrees of freedom" to the examples to be considered similar to the point to predict. Am i correct ?

Comment: No, because if two vectors are very similar in most of the dimensions and very different in one dimension, then the distance can be very big. KNN just selects the closest elements, and this doesn't really care about degrees of freedom, it is just a competition of who is the closest.

Comment: Maybe, the fact that a distance on a certain dimension can get bigger, it's compensated by the new introduced attribute (dimension)

Comment: Why do you mind about dimension being big if you are going to make all the training examples compete?